# reload page loaded with GET request

Tags: php

in the index.php I load a php page depending on a PHP request:

```
<div id="mainContent">
    <?php
        if(isset($_GET['incidentsView'])) {
            include ("incidents.php");
        }
    ?>
</div>
```

**Navigation**

```
<div class="sidebar-nav navbar-collapse" id="sidebarNavigationList">
        <ul class="nav in" id="side-menu">
            <li><a href="index.php?incidentsView" id="pageIncidents">Einsatzliste</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

the incidents.php page itself includes a form where the submit button is being evaluated within the POST variable:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    header('Location: '.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
}
```

So that the page reloads when the submit button is pressed. In this page is a table that shows SQL DB content. After hitting the submit button everything gets refreshed, including the table with the new data. That works fine, if I am directly loading the incidents.php. But when I load the index.php and the incidents.php is included into index.php, and I press the button, nothing gets refreshed at all. Only when I click again the link in the menu. How do I need to rewrite my code, that this refresh is working even when I am on index.php?

Comment: You could use $_REQUEST instead of $_GET and $_POST

Comment: I don't understand. How would this be different when I submit my info to refresh the index page correctly?

Comment: I'll admit I only did a cursory glance at your code but the problem you are describing seems like it would be caused when a page is loaded via a GET versus a POST.  Using $_REQUEST means your checks for isset GET/POST would work regardless of the method used to get to the page

Answer (score 0):

You are including `incidents.php` *after* outputing some HTML (`<div id="mainContent">`), and you can't send a `header()` after you've already output some content. You have 2 options:

1. Rework your code so the `header()` gets called before any HTML.
2. Use a JavaScript redirect in `incidents.php` instead:

   ```
   if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
       echo '<script>location.href = ' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) . ';</script>';
   }
   ```

Comment: I checked the JS redirect but still nothing happens when the submit button is being pressed

Comment: When I tried The JS approach, it at least did not crash in any way, but only when I click the link in the menu again to load the page, the new content is being displayed. So it seems to me as hitting the submit button doesn't really force the page to reload?

Comment: @ISARFAKTOR Does `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` have the value you expect it to have?

Comment: Jup... "/pages/index.php?incidentsView" which I would expect

Comment: This would be the same page thatt is loaded when I click the link the menu, but I think the issue is, that it doesn't "force" the page to reload completely. When I click the link, the whole thing is refreshed